# parsing tables in outlook *.msg emails by python

Tags: python, pandas, html-table, outlook, html-email

I am trying to read outlook *.msg using python and Pandas. I got the body of the emails using a module called 'ExtractMsg'. The emails contain a table which is very complex since there are hard new lines ('\r\n') even within some cells. This makes the converting to Pandas very unpredictable. I am wondering how I could reproduce the same tables in Pandas. Thanks very much!

How an email look like is attached: email screenshot

[image]

my code is here:

```
import ExtractMsg
email = ExtractMsg.Message(file)
email_body = email.body
```

The the email body looks like:

' \r\nA\r\nB\r\nC\r\n1\r\n1a\r\n1b\r\nss\r\n1c\r\n2\r\n2a\r\n2b\r\n2c\r\n3\r\n3a\r\n3b\r\n3c\r\nxxx\r\n4\r\n4a\r\n4b\r\n4c\r\n5\r\n5a\r\nttt\r\n5b\r\n5c\r\n \r\n'

Comment: `email.body` is a plain-text variant of the original RTF/HTML body, in which the table structure is lost. It seems that the `ExtractMsg` module currently doesn't support accessing the original RTF/HTML content, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor/issues/32).

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @Ethan I am not familiar with `ExtractMsg` but you can convert a .msg to an adobe pdf and then export to a .xlsx

Comment: Thanks very much, Chris. Very good point! Just had a quick check (print email to pdf and convert it to excel on a free website). The excel file recognises most of the table but not the cells within new lines inside. This still makes cleaning very tricky if the data don't show regular patterns for those cells.

Comment: @Ethan I was not able to replicate the problem with line breaks inside the cells. I am using adobe acrobat pro to convert the pdf to a .xlsx

Comment: @Chris I don't have an acrobat pro so I couldn't try it. I am sure you said is right that it can convert a table perfectly to excel. In this case, maybe I can batch save *.msg files to *.html. I guess python should have nicely designed modules to parse html files. I will try this and see what will happen.

Comment: @Ethan yes if you save the files as .html the you can use pandas: `df = pd.read_html` then you can simply do `df[0]`

Comment: @Chris converting to html works perfectly! I am sure pdf to excel will do! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Chris One more question. I have hundreds of emails which need to be read by Python and Pandas. How to automate the process since I need to open Outlook, save an email as a html file and next one...? Sorry to bother again.